# Exporting files from docker volume to another directory

Tags: python, docker

I have a python code which reads data from the file and do some calculation and save the result to the output file. The code also saves the logs in log file. So in my current directory, I have below files:

```
1. code.py  --> The main python application
2. input.json --> This json file is used to take input data
3. output.json --> The output data is saved in this file.
4. logfile.log --> This file saves the log.
```

All the above file is inside the directory `Application`. Full path is `/home/user/Projects/Application/`. Now when I am running the `code.py` I am getting the expected results. So I converted the above code into docker by using below `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

ADD code.py /

ADD input.json /

ADD output.json /

ADD logfile.log /

CMD [ "python3", "./code.py" ]
```

When I am running the docker container, it is running fine but I cannot see the output data and logs in `output.json` and `logfile.log`. Then I searched for these file in the file system and found these files in below directory:

`/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c237c143f9f2e711832daccecdfb29abaf1e37a4714f34f34870e0ee4b1af07/diff/home/user/Projects/Application/`

and all my files were in that directory. I checked for the logs and the data, it was there. Then I understood that all the files will be saved inside the docker volumes and not in our current directory.

Is there any way I can keep the files and all the data in my current directory `/home/user/Projects/Application/` instead of docker because in this way it will be easy for me to check the outputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to run your container as below: [you may not need to build your image]

`docker run --rm -v /home/user/Projects/Application/:/home/user/Projects/Application/ -d python:3 /home/user/Projects/Application/code.py`

`-v` ; bind mount local folder into your container at /home/user/Projects/Application/.

Feel free to take out `--rm` if you don't need that.

Please make sure `code.py` write logs to `/home/user/Projects/Application/logfile.log`

To verify files and folders are there are not by running command:
`docker run --rm -v /home/user/Projects/Application/:/home/user/Projects/Application/ -d python:3 sh`

This will drop you in a terminal, you can list files and make sure required files and configs are there.

Comment: By running that command, it gave me an id and it doesnt seems to be working because when I ran docker ps, there was no information there.

Comment: You may run the command `docker run --rm -v /home/user/Projects/Application/:/home/user/Projects/Application/ -it python:3 sh` to get into a terminal. Navigate to the folder `/home/user/Projects/Application/` and make sure you have all the required files, configs etc.

Answer (score 1):

The files are located under the docker overlay volume because you didn’t do volume mounting. To overcome this, you can modify your Dockerfile to look similar to this:

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /app
ADD code.py /app
ADD input.json /app
ADD output.json /app
ADD logfile.log /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app
CMD [ "python3", "./code.py" ]
```

Then in your docker run command, make sure you pass this option:

```
-v /home/user/Projects/Application:/app
```

More information about container options can be found at https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Docker+Containers.

If you are using docker compose, you need to add:

```
volumes:
    - /home/user/Projects/Application: /var/www/app
```